# RegEX: match ([^A-Z]*) but stop if you find "foo"

Tags: regex, windows, filenames, pcre, bulk-rename-utility

I ran into a problem that I can't figure out how to fix.
I have a series of video files with names like this:

```
FooBar-tooGGG1 - s01e01 - (HW) - SomeText.mp4
```

So I have to make sure that spaces are added before capital letters BUT ONLY until "- s01e" appears (thus ignoring the rest of the text):

```
Foo Bar-too GGG 1 - s01e01 - (HW) - SomeText.mp4
```

Looking around I stumbled upon these RegEX:

```
(?-i)([A-Z]{1})([^A-Z]*)
```

Replace with: `$1$2`

---

```
.+?(?=abc)
```

or

```
\w*(?<!foo)bar
```

or

```
^(?:(?!foo).)*
```

and this played a little bit on Regex101 but I can't end up getting only two types of results:

```
(?-i)([A-Z]{1})([^A-Z]*.+?(?= - s01e))
```

or

```
(?-i)([A-Z]{1})([^A-Z]*)/g
```

Respectively:

```
F ooBar-tooGGG1 - s01e01 - (HW) - SomeText.mp4
```

and

```
Foo Bar-too GGG1 - s01e01 - ( H W) -  Some Text.mp4
```

I'm not very good at RegEx but I've been trying everything since this morning, put in the middle, use +? instead of * o. * etc.

RegEX Engine: PCRE2; PCRE.
If bulk rename doesn't fit as software, I also have:
FlexibleRenamer and RegexRenamer (also for Windows)

Comment: On RegEx Renamer (windows) it works . On bulk Rename the `$1 $2` works if you enable V2 (which in theory uses PCRE2), despite this, `$1 $2` in Replace and `([a-z])([A-Z])(?=.*\ss\d{1,2}e\d)/g` as RegEX on Bulk Rename with v2 work

Comment: I added that to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bulk Rename Utility, you can use

```js
(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])(?=.*\s[sS]\d{1,2}[eE]\d)/g
```

Set the replacement to a space. Make sure the `v2` check box is set.

[image]

You may also use Powershell (`CTRL+Esc`, start typing `Powershell` and press ENTER):

```
cd 'FILES_FOLDER_PATH_HERE'
$files = Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.mp4'
$files | Rename-Item  -NewName {$_.name -creplace '(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})(?=.*\s[sS]\d{1,2}[eE]\d)',' ' }
```

Here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zqFgP6/1).

*Details*

- `cd 'FILES_FOLDER_PATH_HERE'` - moving to the folder with your files
- `$files = Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.mp4'` - getting all files in that folder with the `mp4` extension
- `$files | Rename-Item  -NewName {$_.name -creplace '(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})(?=.*\s[sS]\d{1,2}[eE]\d)',' ' }`  renames the files using a case sensitive (due to `-creplace`) regex search and replace.

The regex matches

- `(?<=\p{Ll})` - a location immediately preceded with a lowercase letter (`\p{Ll}` is a Unicode variant of `[a-z]`)
- `(?=\p{Lu})` - a location immediately followed with an uppercase letter (`\p{Lu}` is a Unicode variant of `[A-Z]`)
- `(?=.*\s[sS]\d{1,2}[eE]\d)` - a location immediately followed with

  - `.*` - any text (other than newlines)
  - `\s` -  a whitespace
  - `[sS]` - `s` or `S`
  - `\d{1,2}` - one or two digits
  - `[eE]` - `e` or `E`
  - `\d`  - a digit.